# Getting AEM Child nodes through external javascript

Tags: javascript, aem

I am creating a React application that needs to inherit a secondary nav specific to each product in the AEM CMS.

Let assume we have pages in CMS laid out something like this:

```
- Product 1
-- Child Page 1A
-- Child Page 1B
-- Child Page 1C
- Product 2
-- Child Page 2A
-- Child Page 2B
-- Child Page 2C
```

Now, in the external app if someone is loading the Product 1, I would like to query AEM to get the children nodes for Product 1.

Is this even possible? If yes, how can go about it? I don't know if there is an AEM API that I can tap into or can I use a sling/selector combination to get the children nodes? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/developing-screens-rest-api.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the child nodes of a Page doing a GET request with the required deep level and the "json" extension. 
For example, if you hit this:

```
.../Product1.1.json
```

The JSON result will be something like this:

```
{
    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page",
    "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
    "jcr:content": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "cq:PageContent",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "jcr:title": "Product1",
        "cq:template": "X",
        "sling:resourceType": "Y",
        "cq:lastModifiedBy": "admin"
    },
    "child-page-1A": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin"
    },
    "child-page-1B": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin"
    },
    "child-page-1C": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin"
    }
}
```

If you increase the deep level from 1 to X you can get more information from the child nodes/pages.

[Sling Default JSON Rendering](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/rendering-content-default-get-servlets.html#default-json-rendering)

> As Florian Salihovic pointed out, the Default Renders may be disabled in a Production/Publish enviroment.
>   In this case you can implement a similar functionality with a Custom Servlet.

Comment: Might not work on the publisher - or might be blocked on the dispatcher / CDN level on production instances. Usually the renderers are disabled in production.